# Fixed length 64 Bytes EC P-256 Signature with JCE

Tags: java, cryptography, jce, elliptic-curve, ecdsa

I need a fixed length 64 Byte ECDSA signature with the NIST P-256 Curve.

The implementation hast to use JCE.

The following code sample can generate a signature and verify it.

```
Provider provSign = new SunEC();
Provider provVerify = new SunEC();


    // generate EC key
    KeyPairGenerator kg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("EC", provSign);
    ECGenParameterSpec ecParam = new ECGenParameterSpec("secp256r1");
    kg.initialize(ecParam);      
    KeyPair keyPair = kg.generateKeyPair(); 
    PrivateKey privateKey = keyPair.getPrivate();      
    PublicKey publicKey = keyPair.getPublic();

    try
    {
      // export public key                  
      KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("EC", provSign);
      ECPublicKeySpec publicKeySpec = kf.getKeySpec(keyPair.getPublic(), ECPublicKeySpec.class);

      // import public key into other provider
      kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("EC", provVerify);
      publicKey = (PublicKey)kf.generatePublic(publicKeySpec);      
    }
    catch (InvalidKeySpecException ex)
    {                       
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }


      // do test        
      Signature sig = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withECDSA", provSign);
      Signature ver = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withECDSA", provVerify);

      byte[] data = new byte[64];

      // sign
      sig.initSign(privateKey);
      sig.update(data);
      byte [] sign = sig.sign();

      // Working Signature verification
      ver.initVerify(publicKey);
      ver.update(data);
      if (ver.verify(sign) == false)
      {
        throw new Exception("Signature Verification failed");
      }
```

The problem is that the sign is somehow encoded (I think in DER Format) and is between 70 and 72 Bytes long but I need a 64 Byte (unencoded/raw) signature.

What I have tried:
Convert to fixed length 64 Byte Signature

```
      DerInputStream derInputStream = new DerInputStream(sign);
      DerValue[] values = derInputStream.getSequence(2);
      byte[] random = values[0].getPositiveBigInteger().toByteArray();
      byte[] signature = values[1].getPositiveBigInteger().toByteArray();


      // r and s each occupy half the array
      // Remove padding bytes
      byte[] tokenSignature = new byte[64];
      System.arraycopy(random, random.length > 32 ? 1 : 0, tokenSignature, random.length < 32 ? 1 : 0,
              random.length > 32 ? 32 : random.length);
      System.arraycopy(signature, signature.length > 32 ? 1 : 0, tokenSignature, signature.length < 32 ? 33 : 32,
              signature.length > 32 ? 32 : signature.length);

      System.out.println("Full Signature length: "+tokenSignature.length+" r length: "+random.length+" s length"+signature.length);
```

How to check the 64 Bytes tokenSignature now???
I don't know how to convert the 64 Byte tokenSignature back to the right format

```
      ver.initVerify(publicKey);
      ver.update(data);
      if (ver.verify(???) == false)
      {
        throw new Exception("Signature Verification failed");
      }
```

I have achieved the 64 Byte signature verification with BouncyCastle ECDSASigner. But I can't use ECDSASigner because it is not extending SignatureSpi and therefore not working with JCE complient crypto server.

Comment: Put two integers in a sequence using `DEROutputStream`?

Comment: Thanks Maarten now I got it. I have already tried it with DEROutputStream and failed at the first time.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes you can add your comment as Answer :-)

Comment: I'll try today, but if it isn't forthcoming you might want to add your code as answer.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes okay I have added the answer

Comment: DerInputStream and DerValue were removed from bouncycastle. Do you have any idea how can I convert the signature to fixed lenght using ASN1InputStream?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it working now thanks to @MaartenBodewes

```
//How to Check Signature
byte[] r = Arrays.copyOfRange(tokenSignature, 0,tokenSignature.length/2);
byte[] s = Arrays.copyOfRange(tokenSignature, tokenSignature.length/2,tokenSignature.length);

ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
DEROutputStream derOutputStream = new DEROutputStream(byteArrayOutputStream);
ASN1EncodableVector v=new ASN1EncodableVector();
v.add(new ASN1Integer(new BigInteger(1,r)));
v.add(new ASN1Integer(new BigInteger(1,s)));
derOutputStream.writeObject(new DERSequence(v));
byte[] derSignature = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();

ver.update(data);
if (ver.verify(derSignature) == false)
{
  throw new Exception("Signature Verification failed");
}
```

Comment: Yep that looks like my code. I would not use literals for signature size (in `copyOfRange`) of course but the solution should be correct otherwise.

Comment: Quick question: does the constructor of  ASN1Integer always result in a positive integer?

Comment: I also wanted to use new BigInteger(1,r) first but the signature was always correct. (tested in a for Loop 100 times)

Comment: Better safe than sorry. Chances of one in a million crop up 9 times out of 10.

Comment: I also printed the first byte of r and it works for both negative and positive numbers. But I also think it is better and changed the answer therefore.

Answer (score 3):

It works using `SHA256withPLAIN-ECDSA` instead of `SHA256withECDSA`

Please have a look at the following

[Java ECDSAwithSHA256 signature with inconsistent length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52122705/java-ecdsawithsha256-signature-with-inconsistent-length)