# Converting P1363 format to ASN.1/DER format using Java

Tags: java, cryptography, sign, ecdsa

### BackGround

I have a server which uses MSRCrypto to sign my nonce. I need to verify that nonce in Java. It is well know that MSRCrypto sends it in P1363 format and Java Library requires it in DER format.

I cannot change the server code as I am the client. The server is using `SHA386withECDSA`

### What I need

1) Can someone provide me with exact code snippet to convert it from P1363 format to ASN.1 and vice-versa(ASN.1 to P1363) in **Java**. I tried a few code snippets but was not able to make it work (because those snippets were in C, C++).

2) Is there a library which I can use to do these conversion without writing it myself. Like does Bouncy Castle provide this?

### What I am aware of

I am also aware that I can use BouncyCastle with `SHAXwithPLAIN-ECDSA` or with `SHAXwithCVC-ECDSA`. However Bouncy Castle/ Spongy Castle is slow when running this on Android because it does not do native calls. The support is also available in Java 9 but I am still using Java 8.

Comment: *It is well know that MSRCrypto sends it in P1363 format...* P1363 is a big standard of public key crypto primitives. I've never heard of a "P1363" format, though I wouldn't be surprised if there were numerous formats described in that standard. Neither are ASN.1 or DER truly formats in any sense that is useful. ASN.1 is language used to describe many different formats, and DER is a way to encode and decode ASN.1 structure to/from bytes. As with most stackoverflow questions, this one probably needs code in it to be understood.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk: the widely used (and dead-simple) ASN.1 syntax for ECDSA signature is in SEC1 from SECG, rfc3279, rfc5480, and apparently recent/current X9.62 but I haven't spent money on that.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085: Just the sequence of two integers, right?

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk: yep

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BouncyCastle doesn't have a facility to directly convert one signature format to the other. It does have a general-purpose ASN.1 encoding/decoding library (for both DER and BER, although crypto uses almost entirely DER) which can handle the ASN.1 half, but you still have to do the 'plain' (P1363, CVC, PKCS11, Microsoft) half, which is dead easy on the input (decode) side but a little harder on the output (encode) side. For that format you need to know and use the size in octets of the curve order (or more exactly the generator and subgroup order, which sometimes differs from the underlying curve), which I call n here.

I show very limited error handling, consisting of throwing an uninformative Exception and letting the JVM display it. In a real program you will want to do better, but *what* you will want to do varies.

```
static void SO61860104Convert1 (String[] args) throws Exception {
    int n = 32; // for example assume 256-bit-order curve like P-256
    byte[] plain = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(args[0]));

    // common
    BigInteger r = new BigInteger (+1, Arrays.copyOfRange(plain,0,n));
    BigInteger s = new BigInteger (+1, Arrays.copyOfRange(plain,n,n*2));

    // with BouncyCastle
    ASN1EncodableVector v = new ASN1EncodableVector();
    v.add(new ASN1Integer(r)); v.add(new ASN1Integer(s));
    Files.write(Paths.get(args[1]), new DERSequence(v) .getEncoded() );

    // without
    byte[] x1 = r.toByteArray(), x2 = s.toByteArray(); 
    // already trimmed two's complement, as DER wants
    int len = x1.length + x2.length + (2+2), idx = len>=128? 3: 2;
    // the len>=128 case can only occur for curves of 488 bits or more,
    // and can be removed if you will definitely not use such curve(s)
    byte[] out = new byte[idx+len]; out[0] = 0x30; 
    if( idx==3 ){ out[1] = (byte)0x81; out[2] = (byte)len; } else { out[1] = (byte)len; }
    out[idx] = 2; out[idx+1] = (byte)x1.length; System.arraycopy(x1, 0, out, idx+2, x1.length);
    idx += x1.length + 2;
    out[idx] = 2; out[idx+1] = (byte)x2.length; System.arraycopy(x2, 0, out, idx+2, x2.length);
    Files.write(Paths.get(args[2]), out);
}
static void SO61860104Convert2 (String[] args) throws Exception {
    int n = 32; // for example assume 256-bit-order curve like P-256
    byte[] der = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(args[0]));
    BigInteger r, s;
    byte[] out;

    // with BouncyCastle
    ASN1Sequence seq = ASN1Sequence.getInstance(der);
    r = ((ASN1Integer)seq.getObjectAt(0)).getValue();
    s = ((ASN1Integer)seq.getObjectAt(1)).getValue();
    // common output
    out = new byte[2*n]; toFixed(r, out, 0, n); toFixed(s, out, n, n);
    Files.write(Paths.get(args[1]), out);

    // without
    if( der[0] != 0x30 ) throw new Exception();
    int idx = der[1]==0x81? 3: 2; // the 0x81 case only occurs for curve over 488 bits
    if( der[idx] != 2 ) throw new Exception();
    r = new BigInteger (1, Arrays.copyOfRange(der,  idx+2, idx+2+der[idx+1]));
    idx += der[idx+1] + 2;
    if( der[idx] != 2 ) throw new Exception();
    s = new BigInteger (1, Arrays.copyOfRange(der,  idx+2, idx+2+der[idx+1]));
    if( idx + der[idx+1] + 2 != der.length ) throw new Exception();
    // common output
    out = new byte[2*n]; toFixed(r, out, 0, n); toFixed(s, out, n, n);
    Files.write(Paths.get(args[2]), out);
}
static void toFixed (BigInteger x, byte[] a, int off, int len) throws Exception {
    byte[] t = x.toByteArray();
    if( t.length == len+1 && t[0] == 0 ) System.arraycopy (t,1, a,off, len);
    else if( t.length <= len ) System.arraycopy (t,0, a,off+len-t.length, t.length);
    else throw new Exception();
}
```

Comment: Hey @dave_thompson_085 the above converter converts from ASN1 to fixed format. Is there any code snippet which can convert from fixed format to ASN1 because my server is sending it as fixed format.

Comment: The curve used is secp384r1

Comment: Aditya: Convert1 _is_ plain to DER, Convert2 is DER to plain. secp384r1 (aka P-384) has 384-bit order so use 384/8 which is 48 for n.