# Openssl ECDSA sign input as-is - without digest

Tags: openssl, rsa, bouncycastle, sign, ecdsa

I am trying to sign an existing digest with `openssl`.

Let's say I already have a digest 'mydigest'. With that said I dont want to use:

```
echo -n "mydigest" | openssl dgst -sha256 -sign key.pem | openssl enc -A -base64
```

I have ECDSA not rsa so I assume I should not use `rsautl` which is using the input as-is.

So my assumption is that I would need something which takes input as-is (mydigest) and sign it with my ECDSA private key.

I tried following in order to see if the size of hash created with different hash algorithm has any affect on sign result:

```
echo -n "mydigest" | openssl pkeyutl -sign -inkey key.pem | openssl enc -A -base64
```

and

```
echo -n "my-very-very-very-long-digest" | openssl pkeyutl -sign -inkey key.pem | openssl enc -A -base64
```

but the size of the outputs is same for both commands in terms of output length. I would assume for the large my-very..-long-digest it should return larger output (because it should take the input as-is without shortening (hashing).

========================================

**EDIT.**

Maybe the example below will help to understand what I am asking. This is an example with bouncycastle.

```java
 // sign something
String messageToSign = "something_to_sign";
ECDomainParameters domain = new ECDomainParameters(spec.getCurve(), spec.getG(), spec.getN());
ECDSASigner signer = new ECDSASigner();
signer.init(true, new ECPrivateKeyParameters(privateKey, domain));
MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("Keccak-256");
byte[] hash = digest.digest(messageToSign.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
BigInteger[] signature = signer.generateSignature(hash);
```

Let's assume I have following:

1. hash.
2. keys.

And now I want to create signature with `openssl` which should take the `hash` and `keys` as an input without creating the hash. Basically I want to replace

```
BigInteger[] signature = signer.generateSignature(hash);
```

in the example with openssl.

```
openssl * ????? *
```

I assumed the size of the results should indicate if the hash (with different digest size) algorithm I use for hash has any affect on results.

Comment: It's hard to understand what you're asking. All of your examples, including the RSA, first hash all the input, no matter how large, into a fixed-length output before applying the public key primitives to it. The size of the output will be the same whether the input is 1 byte or 1 petabyte.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Thanks for the comment. I've added an example to OP. Long story short I just want to use openssl to replace BigInteger[] signature = signer.generateSignature(hash); with commandline openssl. However maybe it's not possible :) .... Also I checked post: https://superuser.com/a/943973 . So if I would have `-pkeyopt digest:$hash` it will not do steps 1 of EMSA-PKCS1-v1_5-ENCODE in section 9.2 of rfc3447 - which is basically the hashing?

Comment: I see, thanks for the example. I guess I would expect the openssl commands to return signature in the same format. Of course they won't return the same signature because ECDSA includes a random component.

Comment: This is closest I can get with just the openssl command-line: `echo -n "mydigest" | openssl pkeyutl -inkey ecdsa1-priv.pem -sign -asn1parse`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`openssl pkeyutl -sign -inkey ecprivkey.pem` is entirely correct.

> I would assume for the large my-very..-long-digest it should return larger output (because it should take the input as-is without shortening (hashing).

You assumed wrongly. An ECDSA signature mathematically consists of two integers (r,s) in the range 1 to the order of the curve subgroup; it is completely unaffected by the size of the hash used as (or on) the input.  It is *recommended* to use a hash whose size matches the subgroup -- e.g. SHA256 (or your Keccak256) with P-256 aka secp256r1 -- because otherwise if the hash is too large it is truncated or if too small it is padded and either reduces security.

The same is true for DSA, and mostly for RSA -- for RSA the signature is always the size of the RSA key, and an encoded-and-padded hash smaller than the RSA key is padded, but a too-large one is rejected as an error. (This is very rare, because RSA keys below 2048 bits are no longer considered acceptably secure for use, and no one uses hashes that big.)

The size of an ECDSA signature *representation* -- or encoding -- can vary and there are several different standards. OpenSSL always uses the ASN.1 SEQUENCE of INTEGERs shown in [rfc3279 2.2.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3279#section-2.2.3). So do the standard SunEC and BouncyCastle providers in Java *by default*. The length of the ASN.1 encoding depends, usually only slightly, on the values of the two integers which as you correctly note are controlled by a random value (k) and thus effectively pseudo-random numbers themselves. See (ADDED) [Java ECDSAwithSHA256 signature with inconsistent length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52122705/java-ecdsawithsha256-signature-with-inconsistent-length) and (cross) https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/33095/shouldnt-a-signature-using-ecdsa-be-exactly-96-bytes-not-102-or-103 and https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/44988/length-of-ecdsa-signature

The Bouncy provider also supports '{hash}with{PLAIN-,CVC-}ECDSA' algorithms which do the same mathematical signature but use the simpler representation defined by P1363, simply two (unsigned bigendian) integers of fixed size (equal to the subgroup order size) concatenated. EDIT: And the SunEC provider since Java 9 does so with the different name '{hash}withECDSAinP1363format' (somehow I missed this on first writing). JWS also uses this representation. Finally, the Bouncy *LWAPI* which you showed returns or takes `BigInteger[]` -- the mathematical value -- and leaves the encoding and decoding up to you.

Comment: Thanks! Ah... I didnt realize the output is only (r,s). Thanks for great explanation. So for verification I will definitely need 1. signature, 2. original data 3. public key. Do I also need hash function which has been used for hash/digest computation?

Comment: Vlado: yes, you must use the same hash to verify -- and also the same curve, although _some_ publickey representations (including the one elsewhere in 3279) include the curve spec. However, given there are only about a dozen commonly used hashes, you can probably find the correct one by trial-and-error if necessary.